# Errors running java application on server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I try run application but I have the same error in Eclipse Tomcat, Eclipse Jetty, and when I use ant I copy to localhost tomcat 7 I got this error.

```
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.listener.StartupListener - Initializing context...
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.listener.StartupListener - Remember Me Enabled? false
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.listener.StartupListener - Password Encoder: org.springframework.security.providers.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.listener.StartupListener - Populating drop-downs...
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.dao.hibernate.LookupDaoHibernate - Retrieving all role names...
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.listener.StartupListener - Drop-down initialization complete [OK]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter - Initializing filter 'localeFilter'
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.filter.LocaleFilter - Filter 'localeFilter' configured successfully
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostRepReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostRepReportController.officeTrialCostRepReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialRepertoriumReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialRepertoriumReportController.officeTrialRepertoriumReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.ClosureTrialReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.ClosureTrialReportController.closureTrialReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyController.officeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.UserReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.UserReportController.userReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsEndSuspendReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsEndSuspendReportController.officeTrialsEndSuspendReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostRepReportRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostRepReportRaiffController.officeTrialCostRepReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialOperationReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialOperationReportController.officeTrialOperationReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsExport2UpdateReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsExport2UpdateReportController.officeTrialsExport2UpdateReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportRaiffController.officeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialBailiffReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialBailiffReportController.officeTrialBailiffReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialExecutionListReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialExecutionListReportController.officeTrialExecutionListReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsLackOfFormalController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsLackOfFormalController.officeTrialsLackOfFormalReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyRaiffController.officeTrialsNegotiatorActionQtyReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostReportRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostReportRaiffController.officeTrialCostReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialExecutionListReportRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialExecutionListReportRaiffController.officeTrialExecutionListReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialRepertoriumReportRaiffController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialRepertoriumReportRaiffController.officeTrialRepertoriumReportRaiff(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsExport1UpdateReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsExport1UpdateReportController.officeTrialsExport1UpdateReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialCostReportController.officeTrialCostReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsToEPUController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsToEPUController.officeTrialsToEPUReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportController.officeTrialsDebtsPaymentReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialNoteReportController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialNoteReportController.officeTrialNoteReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
DEBUG localhost-startStop-1 com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsIneffectiveExecutionCostController - Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsIneffectiveExecutionCostController.officeTrialsIneffectiveExecutionCostReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]
```

Comment: This is not an error... Just a lot of debug messages...

Comment: thx i don't seerach this my mistake

Comment: I have the same issue. How could I filter out all those DEBUG messages? This seems to come frome the springframework, but logging is coming from my/your code, although I have no log-statement in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is an error ?

```
com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportController -
Found action method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.itfuture.okapi.webapp.controller.OfficeTrialsDebtsPaymentReportController.officeTrialsDebtsPaymentReport(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) `throws java.lang.Exception]`
```

It's reporting a method signature that *can* throw an exception. It doesn't mean it *is* throwing an exception.